# How can I access the variables in this method

Tags: c#

I have a windows application that sends and receives messages to/from a microprocessor using the serial port.

The application is working fine and does what is supposed to do. Now, I need to make some elaboration with the data I receive back from serial and I would like to access the variable "value" in SetText method. 
**How can I access the content of that variable from another method or class?**
Thanks for helping.

```
 delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { text });


        }
        else
        {
            txtOutput.AppendText(text);
        }



        // capture messages from serial port
        if (txtOutput.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(txtOutput.Text, @"(\+|-)?\d+");
            if (mc.Count > 0)
            {
                long value = long.Parse(mc[mc.Count - 1].Value);


                if (value > 1 && value < 1000)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = value.ToString();
                }
                else if (value < 2000 && value > 1000)
                {
                    value = value - 1000;
                    textBox3.Text = value.ToString();
                }

            }
        }
    }
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            SetText(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SetText(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: By passing it, or making it public to, or making it otherwise reachable for that other method/class.

Comment: Expose a public property?

Comment: create a property that is global..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have done and it is now working.Thanks to all of you for the good suggestions. I am quite sure that I am going to use your examples very soon in the additional developments of the application.

```
 internal long value;
        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (this.txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { text });


            }
            else
            {
                txtOutput.AppendText(text);
            }
            // capture messages from serial port
            if (txtOutput.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(txtOutput.Text, @"(\+|-)?\d+");

                if (mc.Count > 0)
                {
                    value = long.Parse(mc[mc.Count - 1].Value);
                    if (value > 1 && value < 1000)
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = value.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (value < 2000 && value > 1000)
                    {
                        value = value - 1000;
                        textBox3.Text = value.ToString();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this :

Make a property

```
public long Value { get; set; }
```

Use this in your code.

```
if (txtOutput.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(txtOutput.Text, @"(\+|-)?\d+");
            if (mc.Count > 0)
            {
                value = long.Parse(mc[mc.Count - 1].Value);


                if (value > 1 && value < 1000)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = value.ToString();
                }
                else if (value < 2000 && value > 1000)
                {
                    value = value - 1000;
                    textBox3.Text = value.ToString();
                }

            }
```

If you want to make sure that this property retains its value then use static one.

```
public static long Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: @ PradipKT, consider I am a beginner. Where do you place the public static long Value { get; set; }? Outside the SetText does not work.

Comment: Just after the class declaration

Answer (score 2):

If the data is going to be used more than one place then don't hesitate just create a class with the list of output variables that are to be shared among the methods. Create properties for that variables within that class. Now create an object for this class globally and assign the retrieved values from the microprocessor to the properties within this globally declared object. You can access this in any place. Because of this is a windows application the data will retain until you clear or the application was closed.

Here is the code. I have a textbox and two buttons in the windows app. One button to get the data and another to show the data. The data was get from the user using the textbox. After getting the data once on clicking the show data button it will show the data pushed to the object as many times you want.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
  {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Declare Global Variable
    DataHolder objDataHolder = new DataHolder();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here use your code to load the data retrieved from Microprocessor
        objDataHolder.UserData = txtUserData.Text;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(objDataHolder.UserData);
    }
}

// Class to hold Data 
public class DataHolder
{
    // Here have a list variables that you need to maintain that are retrieved from Microrocessor.
    private string _userdata = string.Empty;

    // Here have a list Properties that you need to maintain that are retrieved from Microrocessor.
    public string UserData
    {
        get
        {
            return _userdata;
        }
        set
        {
            _userdata = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, the concept is clear but I need a practical example on my code. I am a beginner battling to get it done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will change my code to include the features you coded. Thanks again, reallyappreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the variable in other class using "Static" variable or instance variable

```
public class Demo1
{
     //Static variable can be accessed without instantiating an instance of Demo1
     public static int Number;      //Demo1.Number
     public string Info {get;set;}
}

public class AnotherClass
{
     void DoSth()
     {
         Demo1.Number ++;
     }
}
```

or if you have an instance of Demo1, say demo1Instance

```
demo1Instance.Info="Sth you like";
```

Comment: thanks for you example but I am unable to use it. Could you make a practical  example on my code?